# Can we use Touch ID in an app?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, touch-id

Can I use Touch ID (or the framework it's built from?) in an iOS 7 app? For example, have the user swipe their finger to unlock an account or page?

[This page](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/01/03/applocker-secure-individual-apps-with-touch-id/) makes me think you can, but I can't seem to find any examples so I'm not sure. I see that the above is a "jailbreak" so I'm guessing this is not available to us otherwise? If this is possible, are there any resources or tutorials?

Comment: It is possible to access it if the device is jailbroken. Unfortunately, you will require private APIs of Apple to accomplish this. So in case you plan to provide an app in the AppStore: it is not possible, currently :)

Comment: @Lepidopteron Fair enough, say I didnt want to submit this app to the app store and really just wanted to run the app on my personal phone. Could that be accomplished? and would that, as you said, require that my phonebe jailbroken? I really dont want to get into the jailbreaking stuff but Private APIs would be fine for my case i think

Comment: I think it might be possible. By making use of a private API it was formerly able to programmatically enable/disable bluetooth for example, which was "prohibited by Apple as well. Either way, I think you have to look for it on your own, which might be some work. But I could tell you, where you can find the private Frameworks ;-) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks

Comment: @Lepidopteron thank you very much, Ill look into that. Throw up an answer and Ill accept it

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on how to use it: http://www.ama-dev.com/ios8-touchid-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS 8 supposedly allows it. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW1

Comment: As a matter of fact I just watched the keynote and was STOKED to see they are going to allow this now!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access it if the device is jailbroken. Unfortunately, you will require private APIs of Apple to accomplish this. So in case you plan to provide an app in the AppStore: it is not possible, currently

I think it might be possible. By making use of a private API it was formerly able to programmatically enable/disable bluetooth for example, which was "prohibited by Apple as well. Either way, I think you have to look for it on your own, which might be some work. But I could tell you, where you can find the private Frameworks ;-) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks